# #NA Error Copy/Paste Excel In-cell Function

Tags: vba, excel

I am randomly getting the #N/A error in Excel 2016 when I am manually copying and pasting individual cells (in the same column) that contain an in-cell custom function.

Cells A1, A3 and A10 contain an identical in-cell function (that works fine).

I want to replace cells A1, A3 and A10 with the value (results) of the in-cell function.

I use the standard copy and paste values operation on each individual cell, i.e. not a range selection.  Should be easy, right?

The copy/paste values may work on cell A3, but not on A1 or A10.

Cell formatting is identical for all the cells, i.e. the ones that work as well as the ones that give the #N/A error. I am doing everything the same way on each of the cells.

If I repeat the operation on cells A1 and A10, sometimes it will work and other times it doesn't.

This is frustrating and a time killer.  I can't afford to try to repeat the operation until it decides to work.

Any ideas on what I should do differently?
Here is the UDF code that is referenced in the cell formula:

```
Function example(Myrange As Range) As String


Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String

strPattern = "^(\d{6} )(- )(Smith)(\D*?)\s*(\d{4}\D)"

If strPattern <> "" Then
    strInput = Myrange.Value
    strReplace = "$1(ZT$5) $2$3 $5$4"

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        example = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)

    Else
        example = Myrange.Value
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: You're pasting only values? What's the formula that is giving the error and the arguments?

Comment: Put a break-point on your the first line of your UDF, this will allow you to figure out where the error occurs.

Comment: Yes, I am pasting only values.  I click on the cell containing the function, choose copy, then paste special values and then hit enter.  Standard correct? The formula is a custom in-cell function, that is the same for each of the cells. The formula I don't think is very meaningful, but in any case it is: =example(B2), where "example" is a user defined fx in VBA and cell B2 contains a text string in this case.

Comment: I guarantee it's not random.  Unless your formula involves the `RAND()` function.    It would be helpful if you shared the formula in question, although the first step is to break it into smaller formulas to diagnost exactly where the issue is.  (See: [mcve])

Comment: The **name** of the formula is not relevant,.  What it **does** is.  (the code behind it).  (See: [mcve])

Comment: The UDF is functioning fine.  The problem is only occurring outside the UDF when I am trying to copy and paste the results returned by the UDF.  Sorry if I wasn't clear or if I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: Pasting only values does not do it with set values,  the UDF does not do it unless it is being pasted as just values, so the issue is with the combination of the two.  Without access to the UDF how are we supposed to help find the problem, when whatever we do with pasting only values does not give us the problem as we are missing half the equation?

Comment: Does it help to change    example = Myrange.Value      to    example = strInput

Answer (score 0):

I changed the formula calculation option in Excel from Automatic to Manual and the copy and paste values operation works consistently now.

Comment: Which means your UDF is volatile.  If we had seen the code we could have suggest methods to make it non volatile, so you did not have to change the settings of the entire application to fix this singular problem.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the additional explanation.  I will edit the posted question to include the UDF code.  Perhaps you can suggest a method to make it non-volatile.