# #N/A Error by Copy/Paste-Value cells which contain UDF in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I now upgraded to Office 2016 and I faced an issue with Excel that mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024751/na-error-copy-paste-excel-in-cell-function) as well. The issue is that when you copy and paste-value a cell contains a user defined function (UDF) over same cell, the value turns into "#N/A" while copy and paste-value over another cell works fine.

For example, suppose the UDF is "=myFunc()" and the cell contains UDF is A1:=myFunc(). So, when I copy cell A1 and paste-value over cell A1, the value turns into "#N/A" and by paste-value over another cell like A2, the value is correct.

Note that my previous version of Excel was 2010 and this issue did not encountered at all.

If it is a known issue of new versions of Excel, how to I overcome this? or I must some changes to UDFs?

Comment: Did you follow the solution on that linked page and Scott Craner's comment about the function being volatile?

Comment: It is not a known (to me) issue in new versions of Excel. While newest versions of Excel do tend to feature issues not previously known, in the area of UDF-writing the most common reason [has been](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) writing them incorrectly.

Comment: @Warcupine I can't see any useful solution in that comment!

Comment: @GSerg I think this issue doesn't depend to UDF-writing, since UDF's result is OK. Another thing is that Excel 2010 doesn't encounter with such issues.

Comment: I think that you used to get away with something wrong in Excel 2010, but not anymore. The useful solution in that comment is marking the function as volatile. Which you may need to do given that it does not accept any arguments, which it most likely should.

Comment: @GSerg @Warcupine
 I tested it with a UDF included some arguments. Also I added `Application.Volatile` to the UDF. But the issue doesn't fix.

Comment: Please show that code.

Comment: @GSerg Please see text file. [link](https://file.io/4zZvWWOrutAt)